# NSwagStudio deserializing error when return type is string

Tags: swagger, asp.net-core-2.2, nswagstudio

I am experiencing the following error: NSwagStudio generates a typescript client which is trying to deserializing json when api return type is plain string.
I am using .netCore 2.2 and NSwagStudio 13.16.1
The client generated is:

```
  if (status === 400) {
        return blobToText(responseBlob).pipe(_observableMergeMap(_responseText => {
        let result400: any = null;
        result400 = _responseText === "" ? null : JSON.parse(_responseText, this.jsonParseReviver) as string;
        return throwException("A server side error occurred.", status, _responseText, _headers, result400);
        }));
```

while the API has the following decorator:

```
        [ProducesResponseType(typeof(string),StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
```

As you can see, the client is trying to parse the *_responseText*, which causes the error. The *_responseText* is a plain string.

How can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a Front End problem. Please, don't minimize.

```js
if (status === 400) {
    return blobToText(responseBlob).pipe(_observableMergeMap(_responseText => {
        let result400: any = null;
        result400 = _responseText === "" ? null : JSON.parse(_responseText, this.jsonParseReviver) as string;
        return throwException("A server side error occurred.", status, _responseText, _headers, 
    }));
}
```